Can't render the simplest OBJ properly
I wrote up a simple OBJ parser, it doesn't really parse what you'd call conventional OBJ (vn ->n because of the switch statement) but I need it for some other stuff and OBJ parsing is just a test so I don't have to write all vertex coordinates myself:
void M_LoadOBJ( char* filename ) {
    FILE* pLMFFile;
    lmf_file_t* pModel;
    char pLine[128];
    BYTE bByte, bPosition;
    INT placeholder;

    printf( "Loading %s...\n", filename );

    pLMFFile = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if( !pLMFFile ) {
        MessageBoxA( NULL, "Couldn't open the OBJ", "Error", MB_ICONERROR );
        exit( -1 );
    }

    pModel = (lmf_file_t*)malloc( sizeof(lmf_file_t) );
    pModel->vertexes = NULL; pModel->normals = NULL; pModel->faces = NULL;

    bByte = 0; bPosition = 0; placeholder = 0;
    pModel->numvertexes = 0; pModel->numnormals = 0; pModel->numfaces = 0;

    memset( pLine, 0, 128 );
    while( !feof(pLMFFile) ) {
        if( !fread( &bByte, 1, 1, pLMFFile ) ) break;

        if( bByte == '\r' ) fread( &bByte, 1, 1, pLMFFile );
        if( bByte == '\n' ) {
            switch( pLine[0] ) {
                case 'v': {
                    pModel->vertexes = (FLOAT*)realloc( pModel->vertexes, (pModel->numvertexes+3)*4 );
                    sscanf( pLine, "v %f %f %f", &pModel->vertexes[pModel->numvertexes],
                        &pModel->vertexes[pModel->numvertexes+1], &pModel->vertexes[pModel->numvertexes+2] );

                    printf( "Reading vertexes: %f %f %f\n", pModel->vertexes[pModel->numvertexes],
                        pModel->vertexes[pModel->numvertexes+1], pModel->vertexes[pModel->numvertexes+2] );

                    pModel->numvertexes+=3;
                } break;
                case 'n': {
                    pModel->normals = (FLOAT*)realloc( pModel->normals, (pModel->numnormals+3)*4 );
                    sscanf( pLine, "n %f %f %f", &pModel->normals[pModel->numnormals],
                        &pModel->normals[pModel->numnormals+1], &pModel->normals[pModel->numnormals+2] );

                    pModel->numnormals+=3;
                } break;
                case 'f': {
                    pModel->faces = (lmf_face_t*)realloc( pModel->faces, (pModel->numfaces+1)*sizeof(lmf_face_t) );
                    sscanf( pLine, "f %i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i",
                        &pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].vertexes[0], &placeholder, &pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].normals[0],
                        &pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].vertexes[1], &placeholder, &pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].normals[1],
                        &pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].vertexes[2], &placeholder, &pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].normals[2] );

                    /*printf( "Pline: %s:\n", pLine );
                    printf( "%i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i\n",
                        pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].vertexes[0], 0, pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].normals[0],
                        pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].vertexes[1], 0, pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].normals[1],
                        pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].vertexes[2], 0, pModel->faces[pModel->numfaces].normals[2]
                    );*/

                    pModel->numfaces++;
                } break;
            }
            memset( pLine, 0, 128 );
            bPosition = 0;
            continue;
        }

        pLine[bPosition] = bByte;
        bPosition++;
    }

    printf( "\n--------------------\n" );
    printf( "Model finished with %i vertexes\n\n", pModel->numvertexes );

    pModelFile = pModel;
}

while( TRUE ) {
    SleepEx( 200, FALSE );
    // Controls
    if( GetAsyncKeyState(65) ) {
        glRotatef( 10, 0, 1, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(68) ) {
        glRotatef( -10, 0, 1, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(87) ) {
        glScalef( 1.5, 1.5, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(83) ) {
        glScalef( 0.5, 0.5, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) ) {
        glTranslatef( -8, 0, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) ) {
        glTranslatef( 8, 0, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) ) {
        glTranslatef( 0, 8, 0 );
    }
    else if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) ) {
        glTranslatef( 0, -8, 0 );
    }

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 );
    //glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
    //glFrontFace( GL_CW );

    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP );

    for( INT f = 0; f < mdl->numfaces-2; f+=3 ) {
        glNormal3f( mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f].normals[0]-1 ], mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f].normals[1]-1 ], mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f].normals[2]-1 ] );
        glVertex3f( mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f].vertexes[0]-1 ], mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f].vertexes[1]-1 ], mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f].vertexes[2]-1 ] );

        glNormal3f( mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f+1].normals[0]-1 ], mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f+1].normals[1]-1 ], mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f+1].normals[2]-1 ] );
        glVertex3f( mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f+1].vertexes[0]-1 ], mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f+1].vertexes[1]-1 ], mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f+1].vertexes[2]-1 ] );

        glNormal3f( mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f+2].normals[0]-1 ], mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f+2].normals[1]-1 ], mdl->normals[ mdl->faces[f+2].normals[2]-1 ] );
        glVertex3f( mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f+2].vertexes[0]-1 ], mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f+2].vertexes[1]-1 ], mdl->vertexes[ mdl->faces[f+2].vertexes[2]-1 ] );
    }

    /*for( INT v = 0; v < mdl->numvertexes-3; v+=3 ) {
        glVertex3f( mdl->vertexes[v], -mdl->vertexes[v+1], mdl->vertexes[v+2] );
    }*/
    
    glEnd();

    SwapBuffers( ____hdc );
}

OBJ FILE:
v -10.125000 9.748589 10.442236
v -10.125000 -9.626411 10.442236
v 10.125000 9.748589 10.442236
v 10.125000 -9.626411 10.442236
v 10.125000 9.748589 -9.807764
v 10.125000 -9.626411 -9.807764
v -10.125000 9.748589 -9.807764
v -10.125000 -9.626411 -9.807764
n 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
n 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
n 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
n -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
n 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
n 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1
f 2/2/1 4/4/1 3/3/1
f 3/1/2 4/2/2 5/3/2
f 4/2/2 6/4/2 5/3/2
f 5/1/3 6/2/3 7/3/3
f 6/2/3 8/4/3 7/3/3
f 7/1/4 8/2/4 1/3/4
f 8/2/4 2/4/4 1/3/4
f 7/1/5 1/2/5 5/3/5
f 1/2/5 3/4/5 5/3/5
f 2/1/6 8/2/6 4/3/6
f 8/2/6 6/4/6 4/3/6

The issue is I can't render it for some reason, it just looks wrong:


I tried changing the glBegin modes (triangle strip, triangles)
Tried ignoring face parameters and just sequentially doing glvertex3f on the incremenenting vertex indexes

What is the reason for picking GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP as render mode? It seems you try to draw three vertices per triangle which should be GL_TRIANGLES.

Did you verify that you load the numbers from the file correctly? You should always check the return value of scanf and related functions to verify you have read what you expected. What happens if you use the values from the file and put them hard coded in your rendering function? You need to identify in which stage your program fails: loading or rendering.

Yeah I double checked parsing of every type (v n and f) it seems to be correct, I tried both triangle strip and triangles but neither display the cube properly , unfortunately

the [mre] article links to an article teaching you debugging. work through it, apply it here.

@Gerhardh I did try hardcoding the vertexes of a cube and it's not right either although the resulting render is differnet it's still not right as if it's connecting the faces wrong or/and some of them are just missing, but the vertexes I copy pasted from a sample cube-draw program. So I'm almost convinced that the rendering part is wrong somewhere

great, so now you know you can ignore about half the code in search of the issue. that makes it easier.

Yeap it was me misunderstanding how exactly indices work, thanks eveyryone
